# How to get CPU "load" of subset of CPU cores?

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, cpu-usage, load, slurm

In my environment, each job is assigned (cpuset) to a subset of CPU cores, almost exclusively. (Actually, it's done by Slurm.)

Since the CPU core occupation is exclusive, can I get/calculate the 1-min average or real-time CPU "load" (not utilization) of the subset of CPU cores, perhaps by examining the processes of the job?

Comment: AFAIK, the kernel maintains a single "run queue" of processes ready to run. The load is the _length_ of this single queue. I'm not sure that you could split a run queue with N processes in it (a load of N) into two or more separate load values depending on CPU affinity. But I might be wrong, and I'm not primarily a Linux user.